# Formatting strings with integers

Tags: python, request

I'm trying to increment the video file names every time they get into my folder. I tried the `+` and the `join()` method but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried integers without quotation marks but the join method wont let me use an integer so I tried with quotation marks but now it won't increment

Here is my code

```
 VideoNumber += "99"
 folderLocation = ("C:/Users/someone/Documents", VideoNumber, ".mp4")
 x = "/".join(folderLocation)
 print(x)
```

Comment: `VideoNumber` should be an `int` and then you can just increment it and use it in an f-string like `f"path/{VideoNumber}.mp4"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can format integers into a string using an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) or the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) method on strings.

```
video_number += 99
video_path = f"C:/Users/someone/Documents/{video_number}.mp4"
print(video_path)
```

Just as an example of how to make your original code work, you could keep your number as an integer and then convert it to a string using `str()` (though note this has a bug because you will have an extra `/` between the number and `.mp4`).

```
VideoNumber += 99
folderLocation = ("C:/Users/someone/Documents", str(VideoNumber), ".mp4")
x = "/".join(folderLocation)
print(x)
```

Comment: now my video is called: {submissionVideoNumber}.mp4

Comment: @tomas Did you put the `f` before your string quotes? That's necessary to make f-strings work, e.g. `f"C:/Users/someone/Documents/{video_number}.mp4"`

Comment: with open (r"C:\Users\{VideoNumber}.mp4", "wb") as f: 
             for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
               f.write(chunk)

Comment: @tomas Use `with open(rf"C:\Users\{VideoNumber}.mp4", "wb") as f:` - you specified `r` but still need the `f` for the formatting to work.

Comment: thank you so much, sorry for being a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the integer into string, so your code will be like this

```
folderLocation = ("C:/Users/someone/Documents", str(VideoNumber), ".mp4")
```